# Quotation marks in Google Search

Tags: google-search

I have been always using quotation marks `" "` to find exactly what I was looking for in the Google Search engine.

Example: even if you typed in Google something awkward like `"9dj 9j 90a j0 32"` it always exactly searched the webpages for the phrase that you typed in.

Now it is not working. The quotation marks are ignored by Google or are a part of a string that is searched.

What happened to this functionality and how can I do this now?

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the result list, you have the button "Search tools". By pushing that, you can specify if you want to see "All results" or want your search to be done "Verbatim".